# Calculating conditional expectation and mean time to failure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, expectation, conditional-expectation

I was reading text on probability where they state:

$$Ex[C]=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}i.Pr[C=i]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}Pr[C>i]$$

Now assuming there is a system which fails at each step with probability $p$. What is the expected time to failure? They calculated this using the above relation.

Assuming $C$ is the random variable which is equal to the number of steps until first failure occurs. Thus $Ex[C]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}Pr[C>i]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^i=\frac{1}{p}$. I was able to understand till here.

Now they say that $Ex[C|A]=1+Ex[C]$ where $A$ is the event when system does not fail on the first step. They reasoned that conditioning on $A$ is equivalent to taking a first step without failure and then starting over without conditioning. I am not able to understand how this reasoning works. Can anyone help?

Further when I try to calculate $Ex[C|A]$, $Ex[C|A]=1.Pr[C=1|A]+2.Pr[C=2|A]+3.Pr[C=3|A]\dots$.

Now $Pr[C=1|A]=0$ as we know system doesn't fail on the first step. Thus $Ex[C|A]=0+2.Pr[C=2|A]+3.Pr[C=3|A]\dots$

Now $Pr[C=i|A]$ for $i>1$ should be simply $Pr[C=i]$ as if system doesn't fail on the first step, the probability of failing at step $i$ is still $p$. Thus $Ex[C|A]=0+2.Pr[C=2]+3.Pr[C=3]\dots$ which is equal to $Ex[C]-1.Pr[C=1]=Ex[C]-p$. Can anyone tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: This is an important result, and a clever presentation, so it is worth your while to try to understand it. (Perhaps the most common way textbooks use to find the expectation of such a random variable is by using moment generating functions or by some other kind of 'differentiation trick'.) Notice that the geometric distribution has a 'no-memory' property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the part where it says "starting over without conditioning."
So $E(C|A) = 0 + P(C=1) + 2P(C=2) + \cdots .$

In general, for a random variable $X$ taking non-negative integer values,
one has $E(X) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty iP(X=i) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X > i),$ provided the series converge.

Denoting $P(X = i) = p_i$ for brevity, the right-hand side is

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty P(X > i) \\
= (p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4  +p_5 + \cdots)
 + (p_2 + p_3 + p_4 +p_5 + \cdots) + (p_3 + p_4 + p_5\cdots) + \cdots\\
= p_1 + 2p_2 + 3p_3 + \cdots = \sum_{i=0}^\infty ip_i = \sum_{i=0}^\infty iP(X=i),$$
by rearranging and collecting terms.

In the particular case of your problem, this identity is used to prove
that the expected value of your 'geometric random variable' $C$ is
$E(C) = 1/p.$ [If it isn't in your textbook, you can google 'geometric
distribution', perhaps starting with the *first parameterization* (column one)
on the Wikipedia page.]

*Additional examples:*

If you toss a fair coin repeatedly, the probability
of Heads on any one toss is $p = 1/2,$ so the average waiting time until you see the
first Head is $\frac 1 p = \frac{1}{1/2} = 2$ tosses.

If you roll a fair die repeatedly, the probability of $6$ on any one toss
is $p = 1/6,$ so the average waiting time until you see the first $6$ is
$\frac 1 p = 6$ rolls.

*Note:* Very briefly, if a geometric random variable $X$ (as described in your Problem)
has event probability $p,$ then its 'moment generating function' is
$M_X(t) = E(e^{Xt}) = \frac{pe^t}{1-(1-p)e^t}$ and one can show that $E(X) = M_X^\prime(0) = 1/p.$

Comment: I didn't miss the part "starting over without conditioning", I just couldn't understand why can we do so. Further you wrote $E(C|A) = 0 + P(C=1) + 2P(C=2) + \cdots$, but in text it is $E(C|A) = 1 + P(C=1) + 2P(C=2) + \cdots$. And I don't know anything about 'moment generating functions', can I understand this before reading about moment generating functions as this came up in the text before they even mentioned 'moment generating functions'?

Comment: And can you please answer my questions - "I am not able to understand how this reasoning works. Can anyone help?" and "Can anyone tell me where I am wrong".

Comment: See the first sentence of this Answer.

Comment: I saw it. Please see the first sentence of my first comment.